# How to changing file permissions of contents in hard disk only for other computers?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, hard-drive, permissions

How to change file permissions on my hard disk so that when I lend my hard disk for someone they can access only the files I wish them to see?
Like,

1. Some files should be read-only so that they can copy stuff from my hard disk, like music and movies.
2. Some are read protected so that they don't have any permission over those files, like personal stuff.

I tried to follow [this tutorial from official windows documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx)

But I don't know how to add a location to other computers other than mine.

[This is what I get for Folder right click --> Properties --> Security --> Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMs8F.png)

Are there any other way around this?

Comment: You would need to know the name of the other computer in advanced and the name of the account that is going to try to access it. It's unlikely that you will get it to work in a way that's reliable. The easiest solution would be to split it between "read-only" and "personal" stuff using two separate devices. Alternatively you could setup something like a VeraCrypt container or similar (though that means people won't be able to just plug it in and start copying files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - once someone has physical access to the drive, they can override any software read/write protections you put on.

An extremely partial solution would be to use encryption for stuff you don't want them to be able to access. This would not stop them destroying it, but, if done right, would prevent them from reading it.

Comment: There is a hard-to-implement and expensive workaround - you could build a NAS using TPM to secure the boot process and Full Disk Encryption which uses tpm to unlock disks ala bitlocker - and export the shares over SMB (Windows Filesharing). This would not stop someone maliciously removing the drives and overwriting them, but the again, someone could just steal your drives in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would invest in another drive, even a USB stick or SD card for your 'giveaway data'.

As soon as the drive is attached to any machine other than your own, then all data is easily accessible to the owner of that other machine.

Unless you encrypted the parts of the drive you didn't want accessed [which really would require some effort to do it partially rather than totally] then it would be a trivial matter for someone with the drive in their possession to simply take ownership of the entire thing & change any permissions settings you had configured.

On a Mac they wouldn't even need that, there's a simple checkbox for "ignore ownership on this volume" & you wouldn't even know they'd done it.